# Sonar violation properly sanitized before use in this OS command

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, java-security

In my project i got a sonar security violation-properly sanitized before use in this OS command. I have done the pattern check for my inputs, but still the violation is not going away.

```
if(Pattern.matches("[0-9]+", empNp)){
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(exeLoc, folderPath, empNp);
```

It still keeps complaining the empNp is not properly sanitized. Could you please let me know how to handle this. I cannot hard code the empNp because it is dynamic input.How to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

The point of many of the security rules is to draw attention to something that requires human intelligence to determine whether or not the code is truly safe. If you're sure the input has been properly sanitized, then mark this issue False Positive and move on with a clear conscience.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was just trying to understand why this still complains that it is not sanitized. Is there something I am missing on this?

Comment: Nope. You're not missing anything.

Comment: And in a perfect world @Harry, would be indeed better if the analyzer was able to detect by itself that this user input was sanitised.